# UIDatePicker size inside keyboard (iPad)

Tags: swift, ipad, uidatepicker, ios14

After migration to IOS 14 date picker style was changed. Wheels style fit to design much better so that I set it.

```
 if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
     UIDatePicker.appearance().preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
 }
```

But then I realised there is one issue with keyboard piker as on screenshot[image]. Is there any way to make picker's height bigger?

Comment: I'm beginning to learn about this new style also, so I am not sure if this is helpful. Can you set the height constraint for the picker view?

Comment: @BillNorman https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258934/10567083

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by setting frame for picker in viewWillAppear(animated)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)

   myPicker.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
}
```